# Why restrict the number of inodes a user can access?

Tags: nfs, inode, quota

It appears that it is possible on a network mount to set a quota on how much space a user can consume.

```
# edquota ramesh

Disk quotas for user ramesh (uid 500):
  Filesystem           blocks       soft       hard     inodes     soft     hard
  /dev/sda3           1419352          0          0       1686        0        0
```

You also can set a soft and a hard limit on how many inodes a user has.

Why would you ever need to limit how many inodes a user has access to?

Wouldn't the user still be able to fill up the disk with 1 really large file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you limit the number of inodes a user can access is so they don't make the system as a whole run out of inodes by creating a huge number of 0-byte files.

With most Linux file systems (e.g. ext3 and ext4), each file (including device files) or directory has an *inode* -- a number used to point to a given file/directory.  If a system runs out of inodes, it doesn't matter how much free space the hard disk has; it's impossible to make a new file until inodes are freed up.

To see how many inodes each filesystem has left:

```
df -i
```

The number of inodes a filesystem has is determined by the `-i` argument when formatting the file system.  Examples:

```
mkfs -t ext4 -i 1024 /dev/foo # One inode per 1024 bytes
mkfs -t ext4 -i 2048 /dev/foo # One inode per 2048 bytes
mkfs -t ext4 -i 8192 /dev/foo # One inode per 8192 bytes
```

The filesystem created with the `-i 1024` option will have eight times as many inodes as the filesystem created with the `-i 8192` option (assuming both file sytems are the same size).  Sometimes, especially with some mail servers (that use "maildir") or old-school Usenet spools, one needs more inodes, since those use cases create a lot of small files.

Note that some Linux filesystems, such as Reiserfs, are able to dynamically assign inodes and do not create all of them at filesystem creation time.

Comment: Interesting. If it is that easy to set the number of inodes per byte, why wouldn't you always set a large inode number when making file systems?

Comment: A filesystem with more space reserved for inodes will have less space reserved for files (I once had a Usenet spool with so many inodes, the filesystem had 30% less space than it otherwise would have)

Answer (score 4):

Sure, the user can fill the disk with one really large file, but that's only one vector for saturating the filesystem. The other vector is more subtle -- you can saturate the number of available inodes. In this situation `df -h` will still look fine, but `df -i` will report that you are out of inodes (and you will probably start to read a lot of "no space left on device").

```
$ df -i /
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      7266304 490108 6776196    7% /
```

At the point that you reach the maximum number of used inodes, no more inodes can be created. In many ways, this has similar symptoms as filling the filesystem with a huge file, except for the fact that existing inodes will continue to function as usual.

Restrictions on file size and the number of available inodes should be used in tandem.